# How does below for comprehension work?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I was trying to solve exercises in https://github.com/dehun/learn-fp/blob/master/src/test/scala/learnfp/monad/WriterTest.scala. Currently I am not able to understand how the below code works, especially line numbers 20, 22, and 24. `WriterString` does not have a `map` method. Also, what is the use of `_`?

```
"writer monad" should {
    "work" in {
      val s : Int = 3
      type WriterString[A] = Writer[List[String], A];
      {
        for {
          x <- 1.pure[WriterString]
          _ <- tell(List("een"))
          y <- 2.pure[WriterString]
          _ <- tell(List("twee"))
          z <- 3.pure[WriterString]
          _ <- tell(List("drie"))
      } yield (x, y, z) }.run() shouldBe (List("een", "twee", "drie"), (1, 2, 3))
    }
```

Comment: there are no line numbers in your snippet and only 14 lines of code

Comment: from the link, lines 20, 22 and 24 are the 3 lines `_ -> tell(List(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you desugar for-comprehension (using intellij for example, or by hand)
you will get

```
  {
    1.pure[WriterString]
      .flatMap(
        x =>
          tell(List("een")).flatMap {
            case _ =>
              2.pure[WriterString]
                .flatMap(
                  y =>
                    tell(List("twee")).flatMap {
                      case _ =>
                        3.pure[WriterString]
                          .flatMap(z => tell(List("drie")).map { case _ => (x, y, z) })
                  }
                )
        }
      )
  }.run()
```

Note `_` (underscores) in case clauses, they basically mean we don't care about the value. And in particular here we don't care because `tell` returns a Writer with `Unit` type value.

```
def tell[W](m:W)(implicit monoid:Monoid[W]):Writer[W, Unit] = ???
```

And `tell` comes from the import `import learnfp.functor.Writer._`

`WriterString` is a type alias for `Writer` which can be converted to `FunctorOps` (which probably has `map` method) - https://github.com/dehun/learn-fp/blob/master/src/main/scala/learnfp/functor/Writer.scala#L16

Comment: thanks @Eugene Platonov . I understood the part how flatmap is being used . But I still have doubts how the results  `List("een", "twee", "drie")` is retrieved . if we are ignoring the value in `_`.
Below is my solution which works fine for this test case .
https://github.com/abh1sh2k/learn-fp/commit/0ded2490d2e423c389578bef466d49da03ce06bc#diff-db5d576f273bf5ccf4aeaabb98be5f24.
I need to understand how flatmp of writerMonadInstance from file monad/Writer.scala is coming into picture here

Comment: @abhishek_rathaur

`flatMap` on Writer works same way as all other faltMaps, if we have `Writer[L, A]`, then it it takes a function `A => Writer[L, B]` and returns `Writer[L, B]`
final `run` call returns Writer's value alongside with the log

when we call `tell` it returns new `Writer` with the log and Unit value, we ignore Unit value, but keep the log
In your own solution

`monoid.mappend(x._1, b._1)` combines logs and then you pass value to `fx` (which ignores it)
Does it make sense?

Comment: I understood how flatmap works for both Writer and WriterString but the part which I did not understand is How flatmap of Writer is being used ? Because we are not using value of Writer into any variable (using underscore _ ) unlike WriteString which we are storing in x,y and z .

Comment: right, `pure[WriterString]` creates a `Writer` with empty log and value, `tell` is the opposite, it creates `Writer` with log and empty (`Unit`) value, so when we combine all of them (via `flatMap`), we pick only non-`Unit` values. And all logs are aggregated even despite that we ignore some values.

Answer (score 1):

```
for {
  a <- A
  b <- B
  c <- C
} yield (a,b,c)
```

translates to

```
A.flatMap { a =>
  B.flatMap { b =>
     C.map { c => (a,b,c) }
  }
}
```

last operation translates to `map` (or foreach if you are not `yield`ing the result), all operations before it - to `flatMap`. Operations are nested (next `<-` means next nested operation).

Similarly `if`s translate to `withFilter`.

`_` means that you are ignoring the value (you have to assign the param of flatMap/map to something, but you might decide to not use it).